# eyebrows rigging is not soft

Tags: rigging

[image]

I made it by applying a mouth-making course on YouTube.

Graybones are controlbones.

Green bone is applied with deform and strech.

[image]

Greenbourne is hidden.

I only raise the front part of eyebrows to make a sad face.

The weightless part does not continue smoothly.

How can I make that part smooth?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think bendy bone is one of the ways to solve it.